# Recursive CTE Multiple Levels

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cte, recursive

I have a table showing which roles recursively grant access to which resources within a database. For example:

[image]

The Default_Role grants access to the App_Role, the App_Role grants access to the Security_Role, and the Security_Role grants access to three tables (customers, sales, users). So a member of the Default_Role is granted all of these, but Default_Role is not granted access to the Sys_Role, and is not granted access to the System or Admin tables.

```
CREATE TABLE SQLTest(
     DBName     NVARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,Privilege    NVARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,PrivilegeType NVARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,PrivilegeDetail NVARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,TableName NVARCHAR(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO SQLTest
VALUES 
('TSDB','Default_Role','Role','App_Role',NULL),
('TSDB','App_Role','Role','Security_Role',NULL),
('TSDB','Sys_Role','Role','Security_Role',NULL),
('TSDB','Security_Role','Table','Customers','Customers'),
('TSDB','Security_Role','Table','Sales','Sales'),
('TSDB','Security_Role','Table','Users','Users'),
('TSDB','Sys_Role','Table','System','System'),
('TSDB','Sys_Role','Table','Admin','Admin')
```

What is the best way to flatten this out so you can see all the access (roles and tables) granted to the Default_Role, without showing additional access not granted to the Default_Role? Like this:

[image]

Tried putting together this example, but doesn't work.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9a27/2

Comment: Apologies if my post wasn't very clear. I updated my post and added a specific question and an example of the result data I'm looking for. I'm not clear how your sample post shows how I can make my query work. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: The dupe shows how to write recursive CTEs correctly, which, apparently, you are after. You seem to be looking for all descendants of your role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As CTE's are for the first test quite difficult to understand, i wrote a approach, with all Levels at the end

The Option at the end is nit needed, but to reduce espeically when you are trying to figure out what happens, you shoukld add it at a low number

```
WITH MyTest as
(
  SELECT P.DBName, P.Privilege,p.PrivilegeType,P.PrivilegeDetail,P.TableName , CAST(P.PrivilegeDetail AS VarChar(Max)) as Level
  FROM SQLTest P
  WHERE P.Privilege = 'Default_Role'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT P1.DBName, P1.Privilege,p1.PrivilegeType,P1.PrivilegeDetail,p1.TableName , CAST(P1.PrivilegeDetail AS VarChar(Max)) + ', ' + M.Level
  FROM SQLTest P1  
  INNER JOIN MyTest M
  ON M.PrivilegeDetail = P1.Privilege
 )
SELECT * From MyTest

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 50);
```

REsult

```
DBName  Privilege       PrivilegeType   PrivilegeDetail     TableName   Level
TSDB    Default_Role    Role            App_Role            (null)       App_Role
TSDB    App_Role        Role            Security_Role       (null)       Security_Role, App_Role
TSDB    Security_Role   Table           Customers           Customers    Customers, Security_Role, App_Role
TSDB    Security_Role   Table           Sales               Sales        Sales, Security_Role, App_Role
TSDB    Security_Role   Table           Users                Users       Users, Security_Role, App_Role
```

Comment: So if you had thousands of users and privileges to query, would you setup a cursor to cycle each record through the CTE?

Comment: the algorithm des what you stated, you start at one point and it works its way upwards. And this does pnly that, for other pruposes, you have to think about other ways. such recursive trees are usually braintwisters. for mor complex data you want,